Webcam no longer working (neither on zoom nor on Cheese)
I'm using a Dell latitude 7440 with an Intel MIPI internal webcam Ubuntu 22.04. I got the laptop in February this year (2024) and I remember having have zoom meetings with the webcam working. In the meantime I had to update zoom at least once and ran the standard Ubuntu software updates. Since yesterday, I can't use my webcam in zoom calls anymore (Zoom version 6.1.11). I can enable video and the MIPI camera is selected, but there is just no video.
After reading through some forum posts, I saw people having had this problem before and suggested to use Cheese to check if it works there. Once I managed to actually open Cheese, it says that the video is not working. Some people suggested to decrease the resolution in the preferences, but I can't even choose a different solution (as in the dropdown menu only has one option, the highest resolution).
Most posts I found are a couple years old or at least from much earlier this year, so I don't know if I'm just late to the game or if there has been a new problem with the camera. Either way, none of the suggested solutions I came across worked for me so far, so I'm wondering if anyone has a similar issue or found a working solution.
Thanks!
I tried:

Changing the solution in Cheese (as described)
Adding my user to the video group
xawtv -c  dev/video0
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and setting WaylandEnabled to false
Blurr and unblurr background in zoom meeting
updating zoom (obviously)


Please edit the question and add what you have tried and be exact and what errors or messages or results you got. Just saying nothing works is of no help.
